# When clicking on an app icon in the dock after it's opened, what event can I receive?

Tags: swift, macos

I am building an OS X app in Swift:

(1) Run the app

(2) The app starts and the app icon appears in the dock.

(3) Clicking on the app icon in the dock <-- How can my app get notification for this action?

I hope to do something after the user click the app icon in the dock when the app is running. How to get notified for this action?

Comment: What is this "dock" that you are saying?

Comment: @Sweeper [The Dock is a prominent feature of the graphical user interface of the macOS operating system.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_(macOS))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implement

```
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool)
```

In your AppDelegate and make your application visible there.

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428638-applicationshouldhandlereopen?language=objc) on more implementation details